# Using Amazon Cognito User Pools with Cordova mobile app

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a web application (Written in React FWIW) that I am attempting to convert to Cordova.  The app makes use of Amazon Cognito to sign up and authenticate users, with Google and Facebook user pool identity providers.

Having bootstrapped Cordova to the point where the app launches on an Android device and whitelisted the relevant domains in Cordova's config.xml, the app itself starts up and I'm presented with a login screen with associated "sign in with FB/Google" buttons.

The current flow of the app (which works fine as a web app) is to redirect to Cognito's hosted UI, which then redirects over to Google or Facebook depending on the user's selection. The problem is that with Google at least, I'm then presented with "403 disallowed_useragent" as apparently they no longer support WebViews using their hosted mechanism.

What is the best way, preferably via Cognito, to authenticate users from these providers?

Comment: https://github.com/vbudilov/ionic-app-with-aws-cognito  and   https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js check links

Comment: hey there! did you get around this?